# Initialized a new react-native app, but not installing to device

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, react-native-cli

I have not used react-native for a while. The old project properly installs to device but now when i am creating a new react-native project and trying to install it to the device, it fails showing the following error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Tracks'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Tracks'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

```
at makeError (/Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Downloads/ReactNative/Tracks/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Downloads/ReactNative/Tracks/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Downloads/ReactNative/Tracks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/kherkatarybhaskar/Downloads/ReactNative/Tracks/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.